# WooCommerce - How to check for current endpoint and sub-endpoint?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Let's say the URL is

https://example.com/my-account/edit-address/billing
https://example.com/my-account/edit-address/shipping

I'm trying to check if the current endpoint displaying is `billing` or `shipping` using [is_wc_endpoint_url](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/). But this doesn't seem to work.

I tried;

```
if(is_wc_endpoint_url('billing')){
  ...
}

is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-address/billing'){
  ...
}
```

All of the above is not working. However, the below code is working for `edit-address` endpoint;

```
is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-address'){
  ...
}
```

is `billing` and `shipping` are sub-endpoint of `edit-address`? How can I check for it?

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-11 has a list of endpoints you can check with that, it doesn’t explicitly say whether that is the complete list, but it doesn’t say otherwise either, so I would assume the former until proven otherwise. If you check the code of the function, you can see it extracts the info from `WC()->query->get_query_vars()`, so I’d start by debugging what that returns for each page in question, and see if you can write your own little “detector function” based on that maybe.

Comment: you can use woocommerce wc_get_endpoint_url() function. please refer this URL https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_endpoint_url/

Answer (score 0):

How about using `is_wc_endpoint_url()` together with `$wp` to check if the displayed page is endpoint and the billing address?

```html
  global $wp;
$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
$billing = home_url('/account/edit-address/billing');

if(is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-address') && $current_url === $billing){ 
   echo 'Currently displayed page is billing.';
}
```